# Kaldi feature dimension error

Tags: kaldi

I run the kaldi tutorial for dummies and i get this error "error getting feature dimension".

Can anybody help?

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: You had actual error above the lines you included in your screenshot. Features were not extracted. For the future when you report about software problem learn to read the full software log output for the errors, not just few lines. Also learn to post log file as a text, not as an image. Text is easier to read, it includes more information and you can search inside it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what  Nikolay said about previous error not appear in the screenshot, this error mostly happened because that the command of creating `feats.scp` failed to be executed, so check if these 2 commands ran successfully

```
steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj $nj --cmd "$train_cmd" data/train exp/make_mfcc/train $mfccdir
steps/compute_cmvn_stats.sh data/train exp/make_mfcc/train $mfccdir
```